# Trying to get .intl to work on my mac but can't figure it out

Tags: php, macos, xampp, intl

I am trying to get my localhost running with XAMPP because it gives me an automatic SSL. And at my work, they work with it. The only problem is that I need the intl.so plugin and I cannot get it to work on my mac.

Until now I tried to get the file out of .tar files from php.net and fire of a command that I found online but every time I get this error

```
Can't locate Autom4te/C4che.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Autom4te::C4che module) (@INC contains: /usr/local/share/autoconf /Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.18 /Network/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Network/Library/Perl/5.18 /Library/Perl/Updates/5.18.4 /System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/5.18 /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18 .) at /usr/local/bin/autom4te line 37.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/bin/autom4te line 37.
Roels-MacBook-Pro:intl roelvoordendag$ ./configure --enable-intl --with-php-config=/Applications/XAMPP/bin/php-config --with-icu-dir=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/
-bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
```

So that doesn't seem to work.
I also found some tutorials with brew but I also couldn't figure that one out.

I am working with XAMPP with PHP 7.1.32.
I am on macOs 10.15.